# Issue in converting a csv file data into dictionary and then writing that dictionary into another csv file in python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, defaultdict

I have a csv file, file1.csv, which has following sample data:

```
state,year,value
Alabama,2012,8.03333333333
Alabama,2012,8.16666666667
Alabama,2012,8.06666666667
Alabama,2012,7.7
Alabama,2013,7.36666666667
Alabama,2013,7.0
Alabama,2013,7.0
Alabama,2013,7.13333333333
Alabama,2014,7.2
Alabama,2014,6.93333333333
Alabama,2014,6.46666666667
Alabama,2014,6.13333333333
Alaska,2012,7.33333333333
Alaska,2012,7.16666666667
Alaska,2012,7.06666666667
```

Now what I want is to have one record for each state with all the values for that state in one row and then write the result to a new csv file. So the output that I want is something like this:

```
Alabama,8.0,8.1,8.0,7.7,7.3,7.0,7.0
Alaska,8.1,8.1,8.0,7.4,7.25,7.6,7.5
```

I wrote this code wherein I form a `defaultdict` from the records in input csv file and then write that dictionary to output csv file but when I write it to output the values filed in output file are surrounded by `[]` and `"` and each value itself is surrounded by `'`. So the current output looks like:

```
Indiana,"['8.4', '8.2', '8.2', '8.33333333333', '8.3', '7.8', '7.2', '6.53333333333', '6.1', '5.96666666667', '5.8', '5.86666666667']"
Maryland,"['6.9', '6.9', '6.86666666667', '6.8', '6.76666666667', '6.63333333333', '6.43333333333', '6.2', '5.96666666667', '5.83333333333', '5.7', '5.53333333333']"
```

My current code is:

```
file_write = open('output.csv', 'w')
    writer = csv.writer(file_write)
    with open('file1.csv', 'r') as handle:
        reader = csv.DictReader(handle, ['state', 'year', 'value'])
        data = defaultdict(list)

        for line in reader:
            data[line['state']].append(line['value'])

    for key, value in data.items():
        print key
        print value
        writer.writerow([key, value])
```

How can I correct the output format?

Comment: `writer.writerow([key] + value)`?

Comment: print ",".join(value)

Comment: writer.writerow([key, ",".join(value)])

Comment: @Omar Your code will write to file list of two elements - `key` object and str created from values of `value` list. Output will be something like `Alaska,"7.33333333333,7.16666666667,7.06666666667"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix your problem you should replace

```
writer.writerow([key, value])
```

with

```
writer.writerow([key] + value)
```

as Mathias Ettinger wrote in comments.
When you write

```
[key, value]
```

you create a list with two elements. First element `key` object and second element nested list `value`.
Instead of it you need to create a list consists of `key` and all elements from `value` list.